# How can I host a resource reservation calendar?

Tags: calendar, reservation, scheduling

I want to create a scheduling calendar that people can use to reserve something (family cabin) for a period of time.  I wonder if there is a plugin that could be added to a Google Calendar, or maybe an OwnCloud application that can do this.  I would want it to do the following:

- Be web-based (possibly login/user selective but not essential)
- Allow users to see times that are reserved/available
- Allow users to modify only their own reservations (add/edit/delete)

I ask here as it seems I cannot be the first to want something like this and I imagine there is an economical solution available.

Preferably free.

Comment: Don't know if you'll find a free solution.  I've worked with a CMS that I've configured for reservations, but, it's hosted on a low cost web service.  I've also hosted it on my NAS drive.  The NAS solution is probably the cheapest, because it's a one time charge and the software is free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Booked Scheduler

The most flexible free / open source software for resource reservations is definitely [Booked Scheduler](https://www.bookedscheduler.com/free-trial-signup). You can download it and host it yourself, or book a 10 USD/month hosting service from the developer.

It provides the features you want: web-based, with logins, availability is visible, and users can edit their reservations.

For accommodation booking, you will typically only require whole-day booking. If you use the convention that users don't book the checkout day, you can simply [configure Booked Scheduler for a whole-day schedule](http://php.brickhost.com/forums/index.php?topic=12342.0) (in practice: create and save a schedule, change its layout, set its only bookable time window to be `00:00 - 24:00`).

### Other options

I have recently done a survey of all free / open source resource scheduling and booking applications. Several of them are specialized for accommodation booking. See [the full list of what I found](https://edgeryders.eu/t/6629).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/?pli=1) to build and host the site (free). You can [Insert Google Calendars](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/157219?hl=en) or [other Google Apps elements](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90569?hl=en) in it.

Here are a few examples/demos, just so that you get an idea of what can be achieved:

- https://mashe.hawksey.info/2010/11/eventmanagerv3/
- http://wpsit.blogspot.ca/2014/09/using-resource-calendars-in-google-apps.html
- http://collaborative-tools-project.blogspot.ca/2012/06/building-booking-system-with-google_27.html

If you're familiar with software programming you'll probably find the above solution quite limiting, but then you might consider a full-custom hosted [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) app (free/paid depending on usage) which also can access the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/).

Comment: How does the functionality of this differ from Google calendar used through my google account? That is what we have been using but people don't pay attention and change other people's reservations.

Comment: It's not just a calendar, it's an entire site/app which happens to use the same infrastructure the calendar uses but which you control entirely. For example preventing people to delete events which they don't own :) I'll see if I can find some examples to add to the answer...