# Lodge holiday accommodation software

Tags: open-source, web-apps, self-hosted, reservation, booking

I'm looking for a software that:

1. manages bookings for holiday lodges
2. is free (as in freedom, not beer)
3. is web-based, so that I host it myself
4. offers API access, or, as an alternative, it can be plugged with custom payment gateways, or it comes as a WordPress plugin that integrates into WooCommerce

Anything similar could do (e.g. restaurant seats instead of lodges or the like), as long as

1. it manages different dates and prices for different seasons (high/mid/low)
2. it supports payments for the bookings
3. it manages bookings for time periods several days/weeks long.

Comment: hmm, the number of answers after four days (i.e. zero), makes me suspect I'll have to write it myself... stay tuned!

Comment: Here is some random thoughts.  You might be able to use owncloud, and its API if you want self hosting.  On the other handle google calendar has a full API, that I use regularly, but you would have to still program part of it .  So either way it would only be the back end solution.  Many plugins for google here:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/google-calendar

Answer (score 1):

I have recently done a survey of all the open source resource scheduling and booking applications. See [my full list of results](https://edgeryders.eu/t/6629).

There are several options that are close or quite close to your requirements. Starting with the most adequate:

1. **[Booked Scheduler](https://www.bookedscheduler.com/free-trial-signup).** My favourite for nearly all use cases, as it's a really flexible piece of software (also making it complex to understand and configure, though). In the latest version it includes payments via Stripe and PayPal ([announcement](https://nickkorbel.com/2018/05/03/booked-2-7-is-out-in-beta/)); the payment checkout process may or may not be comfortable, I did not use that part yet.

   The only requirement of yours that it *may* not support is "manage bookings for time periods several days/weeks long": users can *can* create full day and multi-day bookings with it and you *can* enforce that bookings cover full days ([instructions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/54930)). However, I don't think there is a setting to enforce that bookings are multiple days / weeks long.
2. **[Qloapps](https://qloapps.com/).** Specialized booking system for hotels etc., with payment integration etc.. Built as an extension for the open source Prestashop e-commerce software.
3. **[LoungeSearch](https://github.com/Alspirid/Lounge-search).** Similar to CouchSurfing / BeWelcome, but much less complex.
4. **[BeWelcome](http://trac.bewelcome.org/).** The open source software of [the well-known hospitality platform](https://www.bewelcome.org/). Mature, but unfortunately PHP, an also a very specialized software made for one web platform.